# Gateway poor performance

Tags: spring, integration, spring-integration

I am using a gateway as an entry point to the messaging system. Before going further I wanted to test the performance and I see that the gateway is taking too much time to process each request. I have the following code:

Configuration

```
<int:gateway id="inGateway" 
    service-interface="com.example.MyInterface" default-request-channel="requestChannel"
    default-reply-channel="replyChannel"/>

<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<int:service-activator method="process" input-channel="requestChannel" ref="myProcessor" output-channel="replyChannel"/>

<int:channel id="replyChannel"/>
```

The processor just takes the message and returns a default String "hello". No processing. The test is as follows:

```
@Autowired
private MyInterface service;

@Test
public void testBucle() {
    String test = service.getTest("Hi");

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
        test = service.getTest("Hi");
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long total = (end - start);

    System.out.println("Total: "+total);
}
```

This test takes almost 3 seconds to execute while if I change the service.getTest("Hi") for a direct call to the processor it takes 11ms. Can anyone tell me if there's something done wrong or is it just like this?

EDIT: I'm adding the processor. It is a dummy processor to test the flow performance:

```
public String process(Message<String> data) {
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 11ms it takes because you use your code directly without any messaging background - no GC for immutable `Message` objects (10000) and reflection for method invocation (from Gateway Proxy)
- For me your test takes this time:

> ```
> Total: 433
> Total: 247
> Total: 150
> Total: 145
> Total: 152
> Total: 146
> Total: 142
> Total: 142
> Total: 142
> Total: 143
> ```

It is with `@Repeat(10)` on test method and `<int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel" expression="'hello'"/>`.

- Since your `replyChannel` doesn't do anything special you can get rid of it and you'll get some performance increase, because there is no need to correlate the reply from `replyChannel` to the `TemporaryReplyChannel` from `MessageHeaders`.
- Anyway show, please, the code of your `myProcessor`
- which version of Spring Integration do you use? Wouldn't you mind to upgrade to the latest one - 3.0.2 (http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration) ?

Comment: I was using 3.0.0.RELEASE. I've changed to 3.0.2 and used temporary reply channel. The test takes quite the same time, although if I use @repeat(10), after the two first repetitions I get much better times. Anyway, as you said I guess I will have to deal with message creation and the use of reflection.

Comment: Will it be for you so difficult to test it with SI 4.0?

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.2.8 with SI 3. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to move to Spring 4.